# How do MongoDB indices work?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

I've heard and read a lot of conflicting information about them and I'd like some clarification because I can't seem to shape my Google queries to get the answers I'm looking for:

- Must one use all fields in an index in order to properly utilize an index?
- Is Mongo able to leverage an index if a field in the query is not contained in that index?

Comment: 1) No, and 2) yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand a little bit upon Sergio's comments:

> Must one use all fields in an index to properly utilize an index?

No. For a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes), MongoDB can use the index to support queries on the index prefixes.

For example, assume there is an index `{ "a" : 1, "b" : 1 }`. The query `db.coll.find( { "a" : "something" } )` can utilize this index because `a` is a prefix, but the query would not be able to use the index if it were filtering on `b`.

> Is Mongo able to leverage an index if a field in the query is not contained in that index?

Yes. It's generally best if all fields in the query are indexed, but the query can still use an index that only matches on a subset of fields.

For example, assume the query is `db.coll.find({ "a" : "foo", "b" : "bar" } )`. This query could utilize either of the indexes `{ "a" : 1 }` or `{ "b" : 1 }`, but `{ "a" : 1, "b" : 1 }` or `{ "b" : 1, "a" : 1 }` would generally be more efficient.